# Laravel rename column loss all data

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I create a users table using `php artisan migrate` command:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();

    });
```

After that I just needed to change the `username` column as `first_name` then I change the schema as follows:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
```

If I run the `php artisan migrate` command again, it says `Nothing to migrate`, then I used `rollback`, and I lose all table data.. How can I edit table structure without affecting my data? I hate Laravel doc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with your schema. Your table name is `users`. It contains a column named `username` and you want to change it to `first_name` without losing existing data. You need to create a new migration for this change.

```
php artian make:migration rename_columns_to_users_table --table=users
```

A new migration file will be created in your migrations directory. Open it and change it like this:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('username', 'first_name');
});
```

Save it and then again run

```
php artisan migrate
```

You column name will be renamed immediately without losing your old data. Hope you got it now.

You will find more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#renaming-columns

Comment: Thanx bro.. it works. but first time its getting an error  `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found` there for I just edit composer.json with `"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"
},`

Comment: sorry it should be `"laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"` for lavavel v:5.3

Answer (score 2):

You should create and register new migration and use [`Schema::table()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns) and `renameColumn()` methods to rename a column:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

> To rename a column, you may use the `renameColumn` method on the Schema builder.

Comment: yes I did.. then what is the Terminal command.  I used php artisan migrate  and it says Nothing to migrate

Comment: Maybe you forgot to register migration with `composer dumpauto`? If you've done everything correctly, just run `php artisan migrate` and it will run this migration.

Comment: Thanx..  I didnt know `dumpauto`