# How to create a column in laravel database without losing data

Tags: laravel

Suppose I have a table named "foo" with data and also contains foreign key. Now I want to create a column named "description" in this table. Without reset or rollback how to migrate this table?? Because If I reset or rollback the table then all data will be lost.

Comment: I've answered exactly the same question couple of hours ago, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458055/laravel-rename-coloumn-loss-all-data

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns), you just need to create a separate migration to create the new column.

Create the migration

`php artisan make:migration add_description_to_foo`

Then just set the migration up with the details you want to add, e.g:

```
Schema::table('foo', function ($table) {
    $table->text('description');
});
```

Then you can just migrate it:

`php artisan migrate`

This will allow you to add a column without resetting or rolling back your tables, and thus prevent you from losing your data.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with your schema. Your table name is `foo`. You want to add a `description` column to your `foo` table without losing existing data. You need to create a new migration for this change.

```
php artisan make:migration add_columns_to_foo_table --table=foo
```

A new migration file will be created in your migrations directory. Open it and change it like this:

```
Schema::table('foo', function ($table) {
    $table->text('description');
});
```

Save it and then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

`description` column will be created immediately without losing your old data as last column. In case you want to reposition your `description` column you need to use `after` (in case of MySQL) like this:

```
Schema::table('foo', function ($table) {
        $table->text('description')->after('another_column');
});
```

Hope you got it.

You will find more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: Could not open input file: artian :)